# Kotlin. Java не видит классы Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Добрый день.

Решил потихоньку переползать на Kotlin и тут же проблема.
Есть простенький класс:

```
 package com.example.a1.testkotlin

 class Test1{
     private var scores: Int = 0

     fun addScores(v: Int){
         scores += v
     } 
}
```

когда я пытаюсь использовать его из Java, даже просто, когда объявляю переменную:

```
 package com.example.a1.testkotlin;

 public class TestJava {
     private Test1 t;

     TestJava(){
         t = new Test1();
     } 
 }
```

То получаю ошибку:
**Error:(44, 12) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class Test1**

Хотя по Ctrl+Space Android studio его подсвечивает.
В чем дело? Оба класса находятся в одном пакете. Kotlin 1.1.1
Попробовал перенести kt-код в отдельный пакет, так теперь уже компилятор не видит весь пакет.
Помогите разобраться.
Спасибо.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: Вбил минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизоводимый пример. Все действия по подключению котлин в проект сделал. Если оба класса на котлине, то все ок. Но хотелолось постепенно переходить.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `Test1Kt`.

Comment: Используется ли у вас в проекте плагин gradle-retrolambda? Если да, то какой версии?

Comment: А файл, содержащий класс, как называется?

Comment: Да, и покажите скрипт `gradle`

Comment: Ну и kotlin то уже `1.1.51`. Попробуйте его обновить

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте конструктор TestJava **public**.

```
public class TestJava {       

    public TestJava(){
        t = new Test1();
    }
}
```

Иначе IDEA выдает ошибку: Error:(9, 13) Kotlin: Cannot access '': it is public/*package*/ in 'TestJava'